# react bootstrap Tabs and Nav ttems keep on stacking vertically

Tags: reactjs, components, material-ui

Hi I am trying to use react bootstrap but the tabs/nav items keep on stacking vertically instead of being laid side by side horizontally which I assumed was the default.
For example, Nav

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav,NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class TabsInstance extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs"  activeKey={1} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">1</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">2</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>3</NavItem>
        </Nav>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or tabs

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tab,Tabs } from 'react-bootstrap';



export default class TabsInstance extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} animation={false} id="noanim-tab-example">
    <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">1</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">2</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>3</Tab>
  </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Both stacks the items vertically, even when there is enough space to spread horizontally (eg I allocate a very wide area etc). Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Add the following 2 lines in the head section of your index.html

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```